# Converting a []byte array (java double encoded) to Float64

Tags: go, floating-point, byte

So, I'm trying to decode a byte array to Float64. I've tried a bunch of different ways, found all over StackOverflow, but no luck so far! [Here's the go playground link to what I have tried](https://play.golang.org/p/7GnRyUy2r0).
 The expected value should be `3177408.5`. The original value is a Java double, encoded as IEEE 754 floating-point

Edit:

The value is encoded using the `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toBytes` method.

```
double v = 3445713.95;
long ff;

ff = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(v);

bArr = toBytes(ff)

public static byte[] toBytes(long val) {
    byte[] b = new byte[8];

    for(int i = 7; i > 0; --i) {
        b[i] = (byte)((int)val);
        val >>>= 8;
    }

    b[0] = (byte)((int)val);
    return b;
}
```

And actually should be: `3445713.95`

Edit2:

My bad for actually just pasting code I was given, without thinking much first, Java is not exactly my cup of tea. Turns out there is a problem somewhere along the pipeline (multiple systems communicating), and value is getting corrupted. I'll mark @Ainar-G's solution as correct, since it actually gives back something close to the expected.

Comment: My guess is that you generate the wrong bytes from Java, or the Java output bytes for your number and the bytes you use in the Go code do not match. Please post how you produce the bytes you want to "decode".

Comment: Please post how you're encoding the java value. That string of bytes simply cannot represent `3177408.5` as an IEEE754 double in memory.

Comment: I've edited the post with the method

Comment: You managed to store 3445713.95 in a Java long? Congratulations! Please show actual code, actual input, actual output, expected output and explain why you think the expected output is correct.

Comment: Haha, my bad... Actually the problem lies somewhere else. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I can get is if I use [`binary.BigEndian.Uint64`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ByteOrder):

```
b := []byte("AJ\x02\xef\xe1\xaf(l")
u := binary.BigEndian.Uint64(b)
f := math.Float64frombits(u)
fmt.Printf("%f", f)
```

This gives me `3409375.763158`. Make sure you're encoding your float correctly on the Java side.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/4KGZoWjLTF.